# Creating Binary Tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I'm a beginner in Prolog, and my first assignment is to implement a function construct(), that builds a binary tree from a list. I know there is something wrong or missing in my code, but I can't put my finger on it. I also think a helper method may be necessary, but I can't think of how to go about that.
Here is my code so far:

```
construct([],nil).
construct(E, tree(E,nil,nil)).
construct([H|T], tree(H, construct(T,R), nil)):- 
          T>H.
construct([H|T], tree(H, construct(T,R), nil)):- 
          T<H.
```

Comment: Do you need to create a *binary tree* or a *binary search tree*?

Comment: The single most important question that you don't answer here is what _kind_ of tree you expect. Check out [this reddit thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/qdh6bg/how_do_i_construct_a_binary_tree_from_a_list/), make sure you read the question and all comments (there is only 3 of them so not too much work I hope). Maybe this will bring you closer to asking a good question.

Comment: PS: if you just took the code from reddit I linked above and wrote: `sort(List, Sorted), list_to_tree(Sorted, Tree)` then you will have a balanced binary search tree in `Tree` with all the _unique_ elements that were in `List`. You need to make them unique otherwise it will not be a binary search tree. But this already assumes a lot of things based on insufficient information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

First: there are no *functions* in Prolog, just *predicates*. So, if you write `tree(H, construct(T,R), nil)` (from your 2nd clause), then you've created a structure (or "term") that looks like this:

```
            tree
         /   |     \
       /     |       \
       H  construct  nil
           /   \
          /     \
         T       R
```

which is not what you want.

Instead, you should write something like this (although this won't do what you want either -- see below):

```
construct([H|T], tree(H, Tree, nil)):- 
    T>H,
    construct(T, R, Tree).
```

Second: you should have an easy way to distinguish a value from a non-value. You've chosen `nil` for non-value, so you could have something like `value(V)` for storing a value.

Now, think about what a `node` looks like. It's got 2 parts (left and right), each of which can be either `nil`, a `value` or a `node`. For example, you'd want `[1,2,3]` to produce a tree that looks something like

```
node(node(value(1),
          value(2)),
     value(3))
```

As for an auxiliary predicate (*not* "function"), an obvious one is a predicate that inserts a single value to a tree. So, just list out all the possibilities:

```
insert_value(X, node(nil, nil), node(value(X), nil)).  % insert into an empty node
insert_value(X, node(value(Y), nil), node(value(X), value(Y))) :- X < Y.
insert_value(X, node(value(Y), nil), node(value(Y), value(X))) :- X > Y.
insert_value(X, node(node(A,B), value(Y)), node(T1, value(Y))) :-
    X < Y,
    insert_value(X, node(A,B), T1).
```

etc.

If you do this, you'll find that this isn't the best representation for a tree, but I'll leave it to you to come up with a better representation. (Incidentally, there's no need for all the `node` functors to have 2 elements; it's ok to have `node` - contains nothing; `node(X)` - contains a single item; `node(X,Y)` - contains 2 items).

Also, you'll need to decide what to do wwhen inserting a value that's already in the tree -- does `insert_value/3` fail, does it just do nothing, or does it allow multiple identical values?

Once you've got this working, then you can write a predicate to insert a list of values:

```
insert_values([], Tree, Tree).
insert_values([X|Xs], Tree0, Tree) :-
    insert_value(X, Tree0, Tree1),
    insert_values(Xs, Tree1, Tree).
```

This is a very common pattern; the general form of it is called "[foldl](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=foldl/4)".

And finally, get the whole thing going with an initial value of an empty node:

```
insert_values(Values, Tree) :-
    insert_values(Values, node(nil,nil), Tree).
```

It's also very common in Prolog to define predicates with different numbers of arguments; in this case, `insert_values/2` uses `insert_values/3` with an initial value of an empty node (`node(nil,nil)`).

Comment: This is a matter of style, but creating predicates (or even compound terms) with the same name and different number of arguments can be a source of mistakes. The only place where I would recommend doing it is in the "public interface" of a library, to provide default values for arguments. In this particular case you could also make an argument for making node/1, node/2, node/3 compound terms but I am slightly conflicted about it.

Comment: I often use predicates with different numbers of arguments (or compound terms with different arities), and that hasn't been a significant source of bugs for me. However, it's good to not overdo this -- the it really should be used only where there are "optional" arguments but the semantics are otherwise essentially the same. As @TA_intern says, it's somewhat a matter of taste and experience.

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog, we can use:

- the atom `nil` to represent an *empty* binary tree, and
- a term of the form `t(Left, Root, Right)` to represent a *non-empty* binary tree, where `Root` is the value at the root of the tree, and `Left` and `Right` are also terms representing binary trees.

To make the binary trees easier to see, you can use the following predicate:

```
show(T) :-
    show(T, 0).

show(nil, _).
show(t(Left, Root, Right), Indent) :-
    Indent1 is Indent + 3,
    show(Right, Indent1),
    format('~*c~w\n', [Indent, 32, Root]),
    show(Left, Indent1).
```

Example:

```
?- show( t(t(nil,1,nil), 2, t(nil,3,nil)) ).
   3
2
   1
true.
```

Let `List` be a list denoting the [**in-order**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order,_LNR)  traversal of an arbitrary binary tree, as illustrated bellow:

[image]

Then, since different binary trees can have the same in-order traversal, a **binary tree** corresponding to such list can be described as follows:

```
% convert from in-order traversal list to binary tree

list_to_bt(List, Tree) :-
    (   List = []
    ->  Tree = nil
    ;   Tree = t(Left, Root, Right),
        append(Prefix, [Root|Suffix], List),
        list_to_bt(Prefix, Left),
        list_to_bt(Suffix, Right) ).
```

Example:

```
?- list_to_bt([1,2,3], T), show(T).
      3
   2
1
T = t(nil, 1, t(nil, 2, t(nil, 3, nil))) ;
   3
      2
1
T = t(nil, 1, t(t(nil, 2, nil), 3, nil)) ;
   3
2
   1
T = t(t(nil, 1, nil), 2, t(nil, 3, nil)) 
...
false.
```

If you want to obtain only **balanced binary trees** (e.g., trees such that, for each node, the absolute difference in the sizes of the right and left subtrees is at most 1), then you can include this constraint as follows:

```
% convert from in-order traversal list to balanced binary tree (bbt)

list_to_bbt(List, Tree) :-
    (   List = []
    ->  Tree = nil
    ;   Tree = t(Left, Root, Right),
        append(Prefix, [Root|Suffix], List),
        length(Prefix, Size1),
        length(Suffix, Size2),
        abs(Size1 - Size2) =< 1,
        list_to_bbt(Prefix, Left),
        list_to_bbt(Suffix, Right) ).
```

Example:

```
?- list_to_bbt([1,2,3], T), show(T).
   3
2
   1
T = t(t(nil, 1, nil), 2, t(nil, 3, nil)) ;
false.
```

If you want only **balanced binary search trees** from an *arbitrary list*, then you must sort this list before creating the balanced binary tree:

```
% convert from arbitrary list to balanced binary search tree (bbst)

list_to_bbst(List, Tree) :-
    sort(List, Sorted),
    list_to_bbt(Sorted, Tree).
```

Examples:

```
?- list_to_bbst([3,1,7,5,4,2,6], T), show(T).
      7
   6
      5
4
      3
   2
      1
T = t(t(t(nil, 1, nil), 2, t(nil, 3, nil)), 4, t(t(nil, 5, nil), 6, t(nil, 7, nil))) ;
false.

?- list_to_bbst([3,1,4,2], T), show(T).
      4
   3
2
   1
T = t(t(nil, 1, nil), 2, t(nil, 3, t(nil, 4, nil))) ;
   4
      3
2
   1
T = t(t(nil, 1, nil), 2, t(t(nil, 3, nil), 4, nil)) ;
   4
3
      2
   1
T = t(t(nil, 1, t(nil, 2, nil)), 3, t(nil, 4, nil)) ;
   4
3
   2
      1
T = t(t(t(nil, 1, nil), 2, nil), 3, t(nil, 4, nil)) ;
false.
```